# Не видит using System.Diagnostics;

Tags: c#, winforms, ооп

Код:

```
 static void DisableNetworkAdapter(string adapterName)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/C ipconfig /release",
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "runas" // Запуск от имени администратора
    };

    using (Process process = Process.Start(psi))
    {
        if (process != null)
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
            MessageBox.Show("Интернет отключен.");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при запуске процесса.");
        }
    }
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку на "Process" не содержит определение для "Start", как это можно починить? C# Winform.

Comment: А если `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi)`? Если сработает, то у вас значит есть свой класс `Process` и вы ссылаетесь на него.

Comment: Сработало спасибо, хотя странно вроде пробывал

Comment: Если сработало, значит как я и сказал выше, у вас есть свой класс `Process`, на который вы и ссылаетесь (гдет в начале стоит `using` на этот класс), убирайте, устанавливайте нужный `using` или делайте алиас на нужный неймспейс.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, но у него `Process process`, а не `var process` - вряд ли бы у него привелось к его классу...

Comment: @Qwertiy А `Process` это что? Вот я напишу `Process process`, а в `using` укажу `using `My.Super.Namespace`, где лежит этот `Process`, будет в коде класс из `System.Diagnostics` или из `My.Super.Namespace`? И я уверен, что левая часть начнет ругаться, если не прописать там также `System.Diagnostics.Process`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я о том, что `Some.My.Prosess p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(...)` не скомпилируется почти наверняка.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не скомпилируется, да. Но в коде нету явного указания Namespace, значит класс берется из того, что указан сверху у файла (либо глобальный), а там явно указан не `System.Diagnostics`